# RecycylerView with SortedList shows duplicate items

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, sortedlist

I use an `SortedList` with a `RecyclerViewAdapter` for my list. Therefore I send my items (loaded from my backend in a background thread) via an listener to my `GameListAdapter`. According to the implemented logic in my `SortedListAdapterCallback` items sent to the adapter with the same id should be replaced instead of being inserted multiple times. Unfortunately this is mainly, but not always the case.

This is the constructor of my `GameListAdapter`

```
public GameListAdapter(RecyclerView list) {

    this.list = list;

    gamelistItems = new SortedList<>(GameListItem.class, new SortedListAdapterCallback<GameListItem>(this) {

        @Override
        public int compare(GameListItem o1, GameListItem o2) {

            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(GameListItem oldItem, GameListItem newItem) {

            if (oldItem instanceof GameListHeader && newItem instanceof GameListHeader) {

                return oldItem.getDate().equals(newItem.getDate());

            } else if (oldItem instanceof Game && newItem instanceof Game) {

                Game gameOld = (Game) oldItem;
                Game gameNew = (Game) newItem;

                if (gameOld.getId() != gameNew.getId()) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!gameOld.getTeamHome().equals(gameNew.getTeamHome())) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!gameOld.getTeamAway().equals(gameNew.getTeamAway())) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (gameOld.getScoreHome() != gameNew.getScoreHome()) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (gameOld.getScoreAway() != gameNew.getScoreAway()) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!gameOld.getState().equals(gameNew.getState())) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(GameListItem item1, GameListItem item2) {

            if (item1 instanceof GameListHeader && item2 instanceof GameListHeader) {

                return item1.getDate() == item2.getDate();

            } else if (item1 instanceof Game && item2 instanceof Game) {

                return ((Game) item1).getId() == ((Game) item2).getId();

            }

            return false;
        }

    });

    DataStorage.getInstance().registerListener(this);
}
```

The items are added to the list in this method:

```
@Override
public void onAddedGame(Game game) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(() -> gamelistItems.add(game));

}
```

Even though the items have the same id, I see this in my list:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWYml.png

Answer (score 0):

You compare the response from `GameListHeader.getDate()` two different ways. In `areContentsTheSame()` it's

```
return oldItem.getDate().equals(newItem.getDate());
```

and in `areItemsTheSame()` you use

```
return item1.getDate() == item2.getDate();
```

Although it is not clear from your posting how the response from `getDate()` is generated or what the data type is, I do think that one of these is incorrect. If `getDate()` returns a `String` then `String.equals(String)` is what you want and `==` is incorrect.